# Having a problem with over-complication in my code

Tags: python

I am just learning Python and this is a working Rock Paper Scissors game that I've coded. I was looking at it and it was a bit tedious to type all of the different type faces, and I just overall feel like I'm over-complicating it. Is there a was to make this more simple?

```
import random
print("Rock, Paper, Scissors, Shoot!")
options = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
bot_choice = random.choice(options) 
user_choice = (input("(What would you like to play?...)"))
while user_choice == 'Rock' or 'rock' or 'Paper' or 'paper' or 'Scissors' or 'scissors':
if bot_choice == user_choice:
    print("Game:", bot_choice,"!", "Tie! Try Again!")
    break
elif bot_choice == 'Paper' and user_choice == 'Rock' or 'rock' or 'ROCK':
    print("Game:", bot_choice,'!', "You lose!")
    break
elif bot_choice == 'Rock' and user_choice == 'Scissors' or 'scissors' or 'SCISSORS':
    print("Game:", bot_choice,"!", "You lose!")   
elif bot_choice == 'Scissors' and user_choice == 'Paper' or 'paper' or 'PAPER':
    print("Game:", bot_choice,"!", "You lose!")
elif user_choice != ('Rock') and user_choice != ('Paper') and user_choice != ('Scissors'):
    print("Bad input! Try again!")
    break
else:
    print("Game:", bot_choice,"!", "You win!")
    break
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work, due to https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/3001761. Once you have **working code** that you think could be improved, that's more appropriate for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this in a few ways. First you should make the user input lowercase before comparing.

```
user_choice = input("(What would you like to play?...)").lower()
```

So if the user inputs "RoCk", the variable will have contain the value "rock". As @jonrsharpe mentioned, the code as it stands now won't work because of the way you used `or`. But that's not really relevant to your question.

We can also simplify the winning logic in a more compact manner. First, identify each input with a number (let's use the index in the choices list), and then we will do logic on these numbers. If the user chose the option with index 1 higher than the bot (where 1 higher than 2 will be 0), they win. A clean way to write this condition is `(user_choice - bot_choice) % 2 == 1`.

In all we get

```
import random
print("Rock, Paper, Scissors, Shoot!")
options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
bot_choice = random.randint(2) # The bot chooses 0, 1, or 2


user_choice = None

# Repeatedly try to get user input
while user_choice not in options:
    user_choice = (input("(What would you like to play?...)")).lower()

user_choice = options.index(user_choice)  # will be 0, 1, or 2


if bot_choice == user_choice:
    print("Game:", options[bot_choice], "!", "Tie! Try Again!")
elif (user_choice - bot_choice) % 3 == 1:
    print("Game:", options[bot_choice], "!", "You win!")
else:
    print("Game:", options[bot_choice], "!", "You lose!")
```

Comment: The code is much more compact. But it looks like there might be a small logic issue here. If the user chooses '"paper" (index = 1) and bot chooses "rock" (index  = 0), user loses. Shouldn't the user win in this case?

Comment: Yes, you’re right, it should be the other way round. Edited the post.